# Attach multiple files to form using formkit

Tags: vue.js, formkit

I want to make a form using FormKit in vue.js that has an option to add multiple files, the problem is that when I add `multiple="true"`  as the docs say it doesn't make it that I can add multiple files, here is the code that I done:

```
<FormKit
                type="file"
                name="file"
                multiple="true"
            />
```

but it doesn't allow the user to select more than one file only to change the original one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<FormKit
type="file"
name="file"
:multiple="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

This should be working exactly as you have in your original example. Can you provide more information such as browser version?

Here is a screenshot and reproduction link of it behaving as expected:
https://formkit.link/4308d7828ab90c9a1f41f45a3921afca

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing that link, when I try it out and put in a second file, by clicking on the first file,  it replaces the first, are my supposed to do it like that? if not how do I put in the second file?

Comment: This uses the native HTML file input under the hood — which does not allow for the behavior you are describing. You have to select and add all files at once when the file choosing dialog opens.

We have plans (no ETA at the moment) for a fancy file input in the Pro library down the road.